# Microsoft Word: Table of Figures Ordering

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm currently working on a report but for whatever reason, when creating a table of figures to go with the images, Microsoft Word gets the ordering wrong:

http://puu.sh/5xWsy/0ee1dd057b.png

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, and I've tried re-adding the images and re-adding captions but it keeps happening. It seems a little silly that Microsoft Word can't even count.

Comment: You can manually state the caption number when you make your captions, which is why Word can do those things (it's a Good Thing, since long reports can have varying caption entries, although bothersome if something doesn't happen the way we want it to). He is ordering correctly, in the sense the page order is accurate. I would try and recheck every caption in order to correct that problem.

Comment: Yeah I understand that it does have the page order right. I get the feeling it's to do with the pictures' physical positions within the document but it still doesn't add up. Here are figures 1 and 2 [link](http://puu.sh/5xZ3a/d61ce90da7.jpg) but here are figures 7 and 8 and yet these two work are ordered just fine [link](http://puu.sh/5xZ2q/3d86ee44c8.jpg)

Comment: At any rate, why don't you redo the two first captions? I don't have Word with me right now so I can't write the answer I would like, but physical location shouldn't have an effect. It is possible you added the images at different times and moved them, which might make Word lose track of the ordering.

Comment: I've redone the first two captions with the same result and what's even more worrying, is that sometimes I'll add Figure 1 and label it. When I add another image that I'd like to be Figure 2, it will automatically label it as Figure 1. Then what was Figure 1 is converted to Figure 2. Microsoft Word is confusing

Comment: I'll check this out later. One last thought, if you can analyze the document in Details or Draft view that can "maybe" indicate where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the response, anyway. To be honest, I've never used Draft view before and I'll be tinkering around with it. I'm not entirely sure how it should help though because of my inexperience.

Comment: Are you doing anything special with the captions (as in moving the text box, if you have one)?

Comment: I move the text box, but out of necessity. When I add a caption to the image, Word tends to do some weird things like put the caption in a different page than the image with some text in between them. So I need to re-position things manually. However, I have also tried making space for it and THEN adding a new caption with the same effect as the screenshot.

Comment: I'm writing an answer but I think I narrowed the problem... Word uses the text box's position (probably the upper left corner) to calculate order of appearance in the Table of Figures. This and sometimes the numbering gets phased. To fix this, right click on the number and actualize / refresh the numbering field. Also, don't forget to refresh the Table of Figures.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to reproduce the problems faced by the OP using Word 2007. Using standard Caption options (e.g. both picture and text are aligned to text, and are not free-standing), I could only reproduce the problem when the pictures and/or the text was boxed. By experience I know this problem occurs sometimes, mostly when copy-pasting parts from different documents, but it is difficult to reproduce.

To reproduce the problem:

1. Create a document with some images. For this purpose, I used sample artwork from ClipArt.
2. Change the text molding to Square (i.e. to make it so you can move the pictures to where you want)
3. Add captions. The captions will also be in text boxes.
4. Create the Table Of Figures (TOF).
5. Stretch the 2nd picture box.

The TOF has now the reversed order for the captions.

To fix this, do the following:

1. Select one of the reversed captions' textbox.
2. Select the numbering, then right-click.
3. Refresh/actualize the field. This will make the 2nd caption 1st, as indicated in the TOF.
4. Do the same for the other box.
5. Refresh the TOF. t should show that the stretched caption is 1st, followed by the unstretched one.

---

With this all you can maybe stretch the textbox of Figure 1, with a transparent background, and refresh the TOF. This should fix it.

Comment: In my particular document, I haven't copypasted anything (knowingly). Although to add images to it, I've been dragging and dropping from a folder. Maybe in Word's coding, that's copypasting as opposed to going to Insert > Picture. I've been doing Square text wrapping too for the same reason; to allow re-positioning. The weird part is that sometimes adding new pictures and then refreshing will jumble up the order. I've managed to somehow fix Figures 1 and 2 but I'll be adding a lot more later on. I'll update when I see more problems.

Comment: This is a piece of advice (as I'm used to write college level documents...) but letting Word treat everything as boxes does lead to several problems. In most cases where I have control, I usually let Word just place everything aligned to text. When I would need to do something similar to your pictures, I would create a table structure and align from there.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a caption to a floating object, it is added inside a textbox and is created using SEQ and/or STYLEREF fields (it depends on the settings).

Textboxes are not in the text layer of the document, so it isn't immediately obvious how Word sequences them. As far as I know, Word looks at where the textbox is anchored (you can click the "Show" button to see the anchors) and uses the anchors to decide the sequence.

But the other problem is that when you select the "Whole Document", e.g. using ctrl-A, and press F9 to update the fields in the document, the text boxes are not included, so their fields are not updated.

So if you insert 2 figures, then reposition them in any way that results in the second figure's textbox anchor moving above (i.e. earlier in the document) the first figure's textbox anchor, the typical "select the document, update the reference fields, update the ToC" sequence will not work.

I think the following VBA can be used to fix all the textboxes in the body of the document (as opposed to textboxes in other storyranges such as Header/Footer, but I don't think they can have this kind of reference number in them anyway).

```
Sub updateFigureRefs()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdTextFrameStory)
While Not (rng Is Nothing)
  rng.Fields.Update
  Set rng = rng.NextStoryRange
Wend
Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

It will actually update *all* the fields in text boxes, e.g. Table refs. and anything else.

Comment: Strangely, Word isn't showing any anchors at all when I set to display them in the options. But anyway, you're right in that the problem seems to happen when I try to put two figures side by side so I would imagine the anchors' positioning can cause problems. Also, you're right in that refreshing doesn't always fix. I've managed to fix the original problem myself (I don't know how), but I've set up your macro for use in Word. I'll try it if I run into the same problem with other pictures

Comment: You only see the anchor for a particular item when you select the item. (Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to tell which item the anchor was associated with :-) )

Comment: Oh well I have two figures and one of them shows the anchor when selected and the other doesn't. Here's the first (and this one shows its anchor at the bottom left) http://puu.sh/5yQXs/d5630f26ea.png The second doesn't http://puu.sh/5yQXS/780d2059ed.png

Comment: If, for example, the image was "In front of text", the anchor would be behind the image and would not be visible. I guess in that case if you wanted to check where the anchor was, you'd probably change the image to be "Behind text", have a look, then Undo.